# React Redux: Posting Records partly work with onclick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following code in React Redux. Everything works fine by posting records to server backend as per code below.

```
handlePostId(postid,post_content){
return (e) => this.props.dispatch(Actions.sendData(postid,post_content));

}


<input type="button" value="Post" onClick={ this.handlePostId(post1.id, 55)}  />
```

**Here is my issue**. 
If I change onclick function to code below

```
<input type="button" value="Post" onClick={() => this.handlePostId(post1.id, 55)}  />
```

It will not post records to server backend. And no error is shown in the console is it because of this `() =>`. please how do I rectify this

Here is the entire code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { Actions } from '../actions';


class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};

      }

    componentDidMount() {
this.props.dispatch(Actions.getRec());

    }



handlePostId(postid,post_content){
return (e) => this.props.dispatch(Actions.SendData(postid,post_content));


}

    render() {
  const { post1, posts1} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>       
   {posts1.items1 &&
                    <ul>
                        {posts1.items1.map((post1, index1) =>
                            <li key={post1.id}>


 {post1.content} ({post1.id})

<input type="button" value="Post working" onClick={ this.handlePostId(post1.id, 55)}  />
<input type="button" value="Post Not Working" onClick={() => this.handlePostId(post1.id, 55)}  />


                            </li>
                        )}


                    </ul>
}

            </div>



        );
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
const { posts1, post1 } = state;

    return {
        post1,
        posts1

    };
}


const connectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App );
export { connectedApp  as App  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
handlePostId(postid,post_content){
    return (e) => this.props.dispatch(Actions.sendData(postid,post_content));
}
```

This returns a function which takes a parameter (presumably an event object):

```
<input type="button" value="Post" onClick={this.handlePostId(post1.id, 55)}  />
```

In order to rewrite the `<input/>` tag as

```
<input type="button" value="Post" onClick={() => this.handlePostId(post1.id, 55)}  />
```

you need to also modify `handlePostId()` to handle the event directly rather than returning a function:

```
handlePostId(postid,post_content){
    return this.props.dispatch(Actions.sendData(postid,post_content));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other people said, you're returning a function that returns a function that does something, instead of returning a function that does something. You should choose between:

```
handlePostId(postid, post_content) {
    return (e) => this.props.dispatch(Actions.SendData(postid,post_content));
}
// ..
onClick={this.handlePostId(post1.id, 55)}
```

and

```
handlePostId(postid, post_content) {
    return this.props.dispatch(Actions.SendData(postid,post_content));
}
// ..
onClick={() => this.handlePostId(post1.id, 55)}
```

Alternatively, you can add a `mapDispatchToProps` and declare it there, like

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        handlePostId: (postid, post_content) => {
            return dispatch(Actions.SendData(postid, post_content));
        },
    };
}

const connectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

and in your render method you can do

```
// ...
const { post1, posts1, handlePostId } = this.props;
// ...
onClick={() => handlePostId(post1.id, 55)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a curried function in your `handlePostId` method. This means you are returning another function from it. By doing that you can use `event` object without using an arrow function in your click handler. So this works:

```
onClick={this.handlePostId(post1.id, 55)}
```

But if you add an onclick handler again (arrow function) you should invoke it like that:

```
onClick={() => this.handlePostId(post1.id, 55)()}
```

Notice the extra `()` at the end of the function. But, you are not using `event` object in your handler method, hence you can simply remove the extra function and return your action dispatching like that:

```
handlePostId(postid,post_content) {
    return this.props.dispatch(Actions.sendData(postid,post_content));
```

and use it like:

```
onClick={() => this.handlePostId(post1.id, 55)}
```

Also, if you want to use `event` object like that and prefer using a curried function then you shouldn't use arrow function in your onclick handler.

```
onClick={this.handlePostId(post1.id, 55)}
```

This is enough to use the `event` object and curried function's goodies. But since you are not using `event` object I'm not quite sure you wrote this curried function deliberately.